# tomcat or glassfish as comet server?

Tags: java, tomcat, glassfish, comet

they are both free but i think glassfish has some limitation or when you reach up to a certain nr of users (comet) then you have to pay? is that correct?

if true, could you use tomcat as a comet server?

if not, then which free comet servers are there supporting long polling and iframe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> They are both free but i think glassfish has some limitation or when you reach up to a certain nr of users (comet) then you have to pay? is that correct?

No, GlassFish doesn't have such limitation (where did you hear that?). You only have to pay if you want official support through a subscription.

> if not, then which free comet servers are there supporting long polling and iframe?

[Jetty](http://jetty.mortbay.org/jetty/) has support for comet-style programming. Tomcat has a [Comet Implementation](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/WhatIsComet) (but I find more [complains](http://bill.burkecentral.com/2008/11/12/buggybroken-tomcat-6-comet-nio-apis/) than positive feedback about it on Google). You could also embed [StreamHub](http://www.stream-hub.com/). But I'm not sure about what they support exactly.

Personally, I'd go with GlassFish v3 / Grizzly. The main reason is that you'll find lots of samples, tutorials, etc (not mentioning that you already have downloaded GlassFish and NetBeans). For example [this one](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2008/05/01/dead-simple-comet-example-glassfish-v3-grizzly).

**UPDATE:** While googling a bit more on this topic, I discovered [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere), *a portable AjaxPush/Comet Framework for everyone* (wasn't aware of this framework and wanted to mention it). Quoting its website:

> Atmosphere is a POJO based framework using Inversion of Control (IoC)  to bring push/Comet  to the masses! Finally a framework which can run on any Java based Web Server, including Google App Engine, Tomcat,Jetty, GlassFish,Weblogic, Grizzly, JBossWeb and JBoss,Resin, etc. without having to wait for Servlet 3.0 Async support or without the needs to learn how Comet support has been differently implemented by all those Containers.

But still, I'd go the GlassFish v3 / Grizzly way (and let Atmosphere mature a bit).

Comment: thx for the comet link. so there is no limitation for using glassfish as a comet server no matter how many users i've got?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything like this. As I said, where did you hear or read that?

Comment: dont remember the article. but since you havent heard anything of it, i guess i read wrong:)

Comment: +1 for Atmosphere link. And @noname: you definitely heard wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at Jetty.  Free to use and has a lot of Comet support.

Comment: I don't know.  Have a look at their chat client demo inside the Jetty distribution and see if you like it.